# bash to merge lines in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

I want convert this text:

```
qa-ops01.mysite.com
/dev/mapper/sys-home   58G   26G   30G  47% /home
/dev/mapper/sys-tmp   3.9G  2.3G  1.5G  61% /tmp
qa-ops02.mysite.com
/dev/mapper/sys-home   58G   26G   30G  47% /usr
/dev/mapper/sys-tmp   3.9G  2.3G  1.5G  61% /var
qa-ops03.mysite.com
/dev/mapper/sys-home   58G   26G   30G  47% /lib
/dev/mapper/sys-tmp   3.9G  2.3G  1.5G  61% /etc
```

to this one:

```
qa-ops01.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-home   58G   26G   30G  47% /home
qa-ops01.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-tmp   3.9G  2.3G  1.5G  61% /tmp  
qa-ops02.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-home   58G   26G   30G  47% /usr
qa-ops02.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-tmp   3.9G  2.3G  1.5G  61% /var   
qa-ops03.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-home   58G   26G   30G  47% /lib
qa-ops03.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-tmp   3.9G  2.3G  1.5G  61% /etc
```

I have used

```
cat FILE |sed 'N;s/.com\n//'
```

Is there anyway to achieve this, or should I just write the If... Then...

Thanks everybody for the answers :D (you always show me new things :D)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14483620/15168) by [potong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/967492/potong) is almost correct; it only handles one server, rather than multiple servers, but the change required is small.

```
$ sed -e '/^[^ ]*$/{h;d;}' -e 'G; s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/' data
qa-ops01.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-home   58G   26G   30G  47% /home
qa-ops01.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-tmp   3.9G  2.3G  1.5G  61% /tmp
qa-ops02.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-home   58G   26G   30G  47% /usr
qa-ops02.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-tmp   3.9G  2.3G  1.5G  61% /var
qa-ops03.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-home   58G   26G   30G  47% /lib
qa-ops03.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-tmp   3.9G  2.3G  1.5G  61% /etc
$
```

The script is in two parts, identified by the two `-e` options.  The first part identifies server names; those lines contain no spaces (hence `/^[^ ]*$/` looks for a line with no spaces), and copies the line into the hold space (`h`) and then deletes it (`d`) and continues with the next line.  The second part of the script is only exercised on lines that contain spaces.  It appends the content of the hold space to the pattern space after a newline (`G`); then it splits the line into 'everything up to the newline' and 'everything after the newline', and switches them so that the 'after' (`\2`) comes first, then a space, then the 'before' (`\1`).

This uses the classic `sed` regular expressions; it was tested on Mac OS X (10.7.5) with both the BSD `sed` and also with GNU `sed` without change.  GNU `sed` has options such as `-r` to change the interpretation of regexes which would save you a few backslashes.

Comment: excellent explanation!  i was trying to piece together how his answer worked, and you delivered exactly what i was looking for.  thanks!

Comment: Thanks.  I developed my answer after commenting on his, but completely independently.  When I looked at my solution and his solution, I realized that they were almost identical except for the `1` vs _regex_ to identify the server lines, and for the standard `\(.*\)` vs GNU `(.*)` capturing notation.  So, I noted that as I was writing the answer text.  (Oh, and the Mac `sed` requires the semicolon after the `d`; GNU `sed` is not so fussy.)

Comment: Thanks alot! now I will go and RTFM again, till I get sed into my brain :D, but this answer saved me for today :D

Answer (score 3):

I don't know much about sed, but in AWK:

```
awk 'NR==1{prefix=$0;next} {print prefix, $0}' file
```

#### Update

If that is the case, look for lines with only one field (column), use it for prefix. That means, the only change to the above script is NF (number of fields) in place of NR (number of records, or lines).

```
awk 'NF==1{prefix=$0;next} {print prefix, $0}' file
```

Comment: I'm sorry I edited my question, your awk code works great, but I don't know how many servers I have to check...(sorry for asking twice...)

Comment: The `awk` should work fine with the different servers; it keeps a record of the server name if there's only one column of data; otherwise, it prints the last server name and the current line.

Comment: It is ok, but it happens to be 1 column every N times.
so it produces this as third line:
`qa-ops01.mysite.com qa-ops02.mysite.com`  <--- this line should be removed...

Comment: Gotcha; I misread NR as NF; changing NR to NF fixes the script!

Comment: Great answer, not sed, but AWK sure packs a punch. thanks Hai Vu.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '1{h;d};G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/' file
```

- `1{h;d}` save the first line in the hold space (HS) and then delete the pattern space (PS).
- `G` on all subsequent lines append a newline and the HS to PS.
- `s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/` re-arrange the PS and remove the introduced newline.

Since posting the answer the original question was changed, to take this into account:

```
sed -r '/%/!{h;d};G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/' file
```

This handles multiple servers by saving lines in the HS which do not contain `%`.

Comment: That warrants some explanation, I think.  I'd have to RTFM to decode what it is doing, but for an upvotable answer, I shouldn't need to RTFM.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
awk '!/^\/dev/{header=$0;next} {print header, $0}' input.txt
```

alternatively (functionally identical, but a bit easier to read and understand, IMO):

```
awk '{if($0 !~ /^\/dev/){header=$0}else{print header, $0}}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{if($0~/mysite.com/){x=$0}else{print x,$0}}' your_file
```

tested [here](http://ideone.com/K0kGSK)

Answer (score 0):

Another way using awk is as follows:

`awk '{if ($1 ~ /mysite.com/){a= $0 } if ($1 ~ /dev/){ print a" "$0}}' temp.txt`

1. `a = $0` copies the line to a if that contains `mysite.com`
2. If second lines contains `/dev` then it joins both lines

or other variation of potong sed

`sed -re '/mysite.com/{h;d};G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/' temp.txt`

Comment: Hiya, this may or may not be a good solution - but it's always good to give an explanation of the piece of your regex, so that others can follow along with what you're doing. Don't forget that completely new programmers use S/O as a reference and to learn how to do things. It's nice to give an explanation so they can learn.

Comment: I have added the explanation