# Bash to merge 2 consecutive lines in a file

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I want convert this text on a given file:

```
87665
S
3243423
S
334243
N
...
```

to something like this:

```
87665,S
3243423,S
334243,N
...
```

I've been reading some [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483341/bash-to-merge-lines-in-a-file), but it didn't work... is there a way to do this with a single line command in linux? 
Thanks!

Comment: Yep, I didn't find the above answer, is duplicate.. thank you

Comment: I remembered it, because I had answered that question. Initially, I thought this is the same question link, but then did not find my answer... :D

Comment: :D I tried to find the answer for a while, but I didn't find it, the title "how can I combine these file".. too generic for me! hehe... Anyway I've just voted my question as a duplicated

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed '$!N;s/\n/,/' filename
```

Using `paste`:

```
paste -d, - - < filename
```

`paste` would leave a trailing `,` in case the input has an odd number of lines.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this might work for you:

```
$ awk 'NR%2{a=$0;next}{print a","$0}' file
87665,S
3243423,S
334243,N
```

To handle files with odd lines, you can do:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, NR%2?",":ORS}' file
```

Comment: You might want to use `ORS` instead of `"\n"`

Comment: I agree. This is probably better in case the user has a different ORS set. (We also save one character :) )

Comment: +1: @user000001 idiomatically you could do `awk 'ORS=(NR%2)?",":RS' file`

Comment: @JS Thats a nice one!

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, a pure bash solution:

```
while IFS= read -r l1; do
    read -r l2
    printf '%s\n' "$l1${l2:+,$l2}"
done < file
```

If there's an odd number of lines, the last line will not have a trailing comma.